# Swift, URL with Basic Authentication

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I have a small problem with Basic Authentication for an URL. I tried 2 different approches to this and both work in the Xcode simulator, but when I build the app with both codes, both dont reach the Server in any way. The App is a addressbook and with the URL I go to the Apache Server and download the least .csv file and overwrite the local file with it. The Code is based on Swift 4.0 if that helps.

```
let fileURL = URL(string:"https://"username":"password"@myWebsite/database.csv")
```

For the Second approch I used the code I found on a post on Stackoverflow.

```
let username = "username"
let password = "password"
let loginString = String(format: "%@:%@", username, password)
let loginData = loginString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedString()

let fileURL = URL(string:"https://"username":"password"@myWebsite/database.csv")
var request = URLRequest (url: fileURL)
request.httpMethod = "GET"
request.setValue("Basic \(base64LoginString)". forhttpHeaderField: "Authorization")

_ = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self)
```

Both work in the Simulator, on at least 4 different tested devices. They authorize to the Server download the file, everything works. But as a App it does not what its supposed to be doing.

Comment: It's your app that you are running in the simulator so in that sense there is no difference so it looks network related. Can you access the url from your phone using a web browser?

Comment: I can access the apache Server from my macbook threw safari and the app simulator and threw the safari on the iphone. It appears that the app doesnt send a request to the server from the iPhone.

Comment: looks like your device is not connected with your LAN and your api url is local.

Comment: show URL too if you can.

Comment: i managed to find the solution, after i build the app i use the mdx toolkit provided by citrix to build a .mdx file out of it, long story short, the app had no network access. nethertheless Thanks for your support.

Comment: Not working this URL:
let fileURL = URL(string:"https://"username":"password"@myWebsite/database.csv")